# Android fragment with web services

Tags: java, android

I am invoking the web service inside fragment. The Bankranking list from web service has the value and I am able to print. But after the method `onSuccess`, if the print the list I am getting array index out of bound Exception.

```
public class BankRatingOffsiteIndustry extends Fragment {

    List<BankRankingDTO> bankRanking = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.add("date", "2017-12-31");
        params.add("currency", "EL");
        invokeWebS(params);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bankrankinginfo, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    public void invokeWebS(RequestParams params) {
        final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("url", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                ObjectMapper mapperObject = new ObjectMapper();
                System.out.println("Input Json: " + response.toString());
                    bankRanking  = mapperObject.readValue(response.toString(), mapperObject.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, BankRankingDTO.class));

                 /*  setResultList(resultList);*/
                    Log.i("exit",bankRanking.get(0).getInstitutionName());
                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

    Log.i("values",bankRanking.get(0).getInstitutionName());
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.menuapplication, PID: 18658
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `bankRanking` list size if is not empty then it work. And you can also used for each loop to print list like below code:

```
if (!bankRanking.isEmpty()){
    for(BankRankingDTO object:bankRanking) {
        Log.i("values", object.getInstitutionName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the problem. The statements are already surrounded with `try/catch` which should avoid the crash. Though the code is not provided properly here I guess. Please see the answer that I have provided below. I think that might be the case here. Thanks.

Comment: I have a values in the list inside onSuccess method.. but values is getting cleared after onSuccess method..

Comment: not possible to clear list automatically used addAll() and add() method to add data.

Comment: even if i use add() method the list values after onSucess() method is getting cleared

Comment: try printing a data outside of this method invokeWebS() .once this method call then after print data.

Comment: same exception if i print outside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show a log when the web service call is yet to return. The web service call is `Async`. So you need to wait for the values to be returned to the application and then print the log.

Just move the following line inside your `onSuccess` function.

```
Log.i("values",bankRanking.get(0).getInstitutionName());
```

Comment: i have the values in the list inside onSuccess function but after the execution of onSucess  function the values in the list is getting cleared

Comment: No its not getting cleared. I think your idea about `Async` operation is wanting here. The `invokeWebS` is called Asynchronously. So when you are logging immediately after the `invokeWebS` called, it has no value in it.

Comment: What is the solution for that

Comment: Just the way I stated in my solution. You need to access the values of `bankRanking` variable inside your `onSuccess` function where the data is available after getting the result from the web service called.

Comment: The same code is working if the replace the code inside activity..but in fragment i am facing this issue

Comment: i need the list for later processing.i need to display the list items in textview. Is there any other way to retain the values in list?

Comment: Where are you using the `bankRanking` variable now?

Comment: i need to create table using the data in the list

Comment: Initiate the create table operation inside `onSuccess` method then.